# rigify, sticky situation

Tags: rigify

I used default horse rig and deleted the rest, when I generate the rig it only generates a plate with confusing circles on it, can't use them in pose mode, here is the blend file, please ignore the trashy mesh i dont intend to use textures on this model.

I would like to know how to make the generated rig work, like being able to open the goat's mouth and rotate its head with the generated rig. I'd prefer a generated rig rather than a bone structure as the bone structure can be quite counter productive when applying movements to the model.

[image]

update:
the bones of the matarig
[image: rig bines]

the bones inside the generated rig's folder
[image: bones of the generated rig]

EDIT: all the tutorials I've watched don't have this type of problems, if you know what it's called or which part of the rigging should I look into that would be great.

sticky mouth
[image: sticky mouth]

Comment: Hi! Consider that this site is no regular forum rather a Q&A site so what's your question? Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @brockmann fixed.

Comment: Apply rotation and scale (Ctrl A) to the metarig before generating. After generating the rig, hide the metarig and parent your meshes to the rig itself (that with the "confusing circles"). https://docs.blender.org/manual/it/dev/addons/rigging/rigify/basics.html

Comment: @joshsanfelici hi, thanks for the answer, but the rig is not in place where I placed the bones when I generate matarig after I apply the transform, should I manually adjust them again or is there anything else I did wrong that caused this problem? I will add pictures to the first post.

Comment: you need to give it some corrections in Weight Paint mode

Comment: Apply location tot the metarig also.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've fixed the previous problem, but new question appeared, when I rigged them correctly, some part of the upper lip and the lower lip sticked together when moving, what is this called? and how can I fix it? tyvm

Comment: Please use a title on the question that describes the issue, not just a vague notion.